# How to return multiple columns (each a composite type) in plpythonu

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I have created a plpythonu function that should return a table with multiple columns. At present, it returns a single column with multiple components.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866321/how-to-split-a-type-into-multiple-columns-in-postgres) answer which is A) a little old and B) requires me to separate the components into a table outside of the function.

Here's a simple function that illustrates the problem:

```
CREATE TYPE foo AS (a INT, b INT);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bar () RETURNS SETOF foo AS $$
    return [(1,2),(3,4)]
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

SELECT bar();
```

This returns two records but only a single column. I want it to return a table with two records and two columns. Is this not possible? That would seem odd but an hour's worth of Googling has gotten me nowhere.

Comment: What about `return [((1,2),(3,4)]` ( a one-element list, containing a tuple with inner tuples) ?

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work. You have a typo, but I assume you intended it to be [((1,2)),((3,4))]. Trying it as [((1,2),(3,4))] returns a syntax error.

Comment: No, I meant `[((1,2),(3,4))]`. You're right that I had a typo, I missed a closing paren. It should be a 1-element list, containing a 2-element tuple, each element of which is a 2-element tuple. If plpythonu supports representing composite types as tuples, that should work. I haven't tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to do that would be to call your `bar()` function like this:

```
postgres@[local]:5432:postgres:=# SELECT * FROM bar();
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
(2 rows)

Time: 0.622 ms
postgres@[local]:5432:postgres:=#
```

Which returns as a record type in this context, with two rows and two columns.

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: Perhaps my code runs differently on your machine, but that's not the output that I get.from my code snippet. I see two rows but the two values are combined into a single column as a tuple.

Comment: Oh. Interesting. I got those results on PostgreSQL 9.4 by copy-pasting your code and doing `SELECT * FROM bar()` above instead of the `SELECT bar()`. Which leads me to ask the question I should have asked beforehand, what version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: Huh. i never thought to try SELECT * FROM bar() instead of SELECT bar(). Rookie mistake, I guess. Thanks for pointing it out.